# On which or To +Verb?

Tags: sentence-structure

In this sentence:

1. I need a piano of my own on which to practice.
2. I need a piano of my own to practice on it.

Which of the two answers is correct and why?

What if "of my own" is deleted?

What should I study so that I won't have such problems?

Comment: Sorry the form came out a little fuzzy . I need a piano of my own 1-on which to practice 2-to practice on it

Answer (score 3):

Sentence one is correct.

In sentence two, "it" is something other than the piano and the piano is the thing that will be practised on "it".  Consider this sentence:

> I have a stage and now I need a piano to practise on it.

This means that you want to practise the piano on the stage.

If you omit the "it" in sentence two:

> I need a piano of my own to practice on.

It become an acceptable - and more common - form of the sentence  even though ending a sentence with a preposition is something up with which pedants will not put.

The "of my own" clause makes no difference to the sentence structure.